# htaccess rule for redirect of all non-directory and non-file requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that I need a catch-all for non-directory and non-file requests to re-direct back to the HTTP_HOST.  I have a re-write rule to only serve extension-less PHP files and an always resolve to the www.HTTP_HOST from naked domain requests.  Here's my htaccess file:

```
#Main Page
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Cache Control for Images and Assets
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

# Never Use the naked domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

# Never Use the naked domain and Remove PHP extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(php|cfm)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.(cfm|php)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Re-direct Non-file Non-directories to HTTP_HOST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)((\?.*)|())$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]

# unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

My 4th rule-set doesn't seem to be working the way I need it to, not sure why.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Is this `# Re-direct Non-file...` not working?

Comment: It seems to be working now.  Not sure if an older version of the htaccess file got cached or what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the non-file request filtering using `mod_rewrite`, consider using `FallbackResource`:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

This is easier to maintain, and should be easier for Apache to process.

Comment: This solution works great for resolving a defined existing file and not returning a 404.  However, the URL requested is still appended to the host, which isn't good for SEO.  A re-write is still needed.